# Conditional javascript formula depending on whether checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I have tried a thousand different tutorials and I'm pretty sure my code is correct, yet I can't get this to work. I'm trying to create a calculation that has a different value based on whether the user selects 'yes' or 'no'.

```js
var people = document.getElementById('how-many');
people.onkeyup = function() {

  guests = people.value;

  if (document.getElementById('leftoversyes').checked) {
    feeds = people.value * 2;
  } else {
    feeds = people.value * 1.5;
  }


  document.getElementById('turkey-number').innerHTML = guests;
  document.getElementById('turkey-weight').innerHTML = feeds;
}
```

```html
<form id="calculator">
  <p>
    <label for="how-many">How many people do you plan to feed?</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="how-many" id="how-many" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="leftovers">Would you like to have leftovers?</label>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="leftoversyes" value="Yes" id="leftoversyes" />Yes &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="leftoversno" value="No" id="leftoversno" />No</p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" class="btn" />
    <input type="reset" value="clear" id="clearcalculator" />
  </p>
</form>
<p>A <span id="turkey-weight"></span>-pound turkey will feed <span id="turkey-number"></span> guests<span id="turkey-leftovers"></span>.</p>
```

It works in that it will give me the multiply of 1.5, but nothing I do can get it to give me the multiply of 2.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. If I check "Yes" and type 2 I get 4. If I uncheck "Yes" and type 2 I get 3. Of course checking "No" does nothing since you haven't bound a handler to it. It also doesn't make sense to have a two checkboxes representing yes and no. Either use a single checkbox or 2 (grouped) radio buttons.

Comment: Works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/9vv61smo/

Comment: Since the leftovers question can only have one answer (either Yes OR No, not both), you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: So now that we clarified that your code sort of works, the question is, how do *you* expect it work? What exactly are you doing that you expect to work but doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `feeds` variable , use `onchange` event of `#leftovers` element to call same function as `onkeyup` for `#people` element

```js
var people = document.getElementById('how-many');
var leftovers = document.getElementById('leftoversyes');
function feeder() {
    var feeds;
    guests = people.value;

        if (document.getElementById('leftoversyes').checked){
            feeds = people.value * 2;
        } else {
            feeds = people.value * 1.5;
        }   


    document.getElementById('turkey-number').innerHTML = guests;
    document.getElementById('turkey-weight').innerHTML = feeds;
}

people.onkeyup = feeder;
leftovers.onchange = feeder;
```

```html
<form id="calculator">
    <p>
        <label for="how-many">How many people do you plan to feed?</label><br />
        <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="how-many" id="how-many" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="leftovers">Would you like to have leftovers?</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="leftoversyes" value="Yes" id="leftoversyes" /> Yes &nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="leftoversno" value="No" id="leftoversno" /> No</p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" class="btn" />
        <input type="reset" value="clear" id="clearcalculator" /></p>
</form> 
<p>A <span id="turkey-weight"></span>-pound turkey will feed <span id="turkey-number"></span> guests<span id="turkey-leftovers"></span>.</p>
```

Comment: if going to declare one as local shouldn't also do `gusests`?

Comment: While this is good practice, it doesn't change the behavior of the code.

Comment: `people.onkeyup = feeder = leftovers.onchange = feeder;` should probably be `people.onkeyup = leftovers.onchange = feeder;`. It works but is very confusing.

Comment: @FelixKling  Yes, that was intent, updated to avoid confusion

Comment: This one worked for me... thank you! :) So, one last issue... I've changed the checkboxes to radio buttons. I notice that if I select no and then calculate, and then switch to yes, the calculation doesn't change. But if I select no and then switch to yes, it does change. Anything I can do to let you toggle the options? (See https://jsfiddle.net/yaylaurie/Lsk4y1na/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another listener for when the value of `<input type="checkbox" name="leftoversyes" value="Yes" id="leftoversyes" />` changes.

```
document.getElementById('leftoversyes').onchange = function() {
    var guests = document.getElementById('how-many').value;
    var feeds;

    if (document.getElementById('leftoversyes').checked){
        feeds = guests * 2;
    } else {
        feeds = guests * 1.5;
    }   

    document.getElementById('turkey-number').innerHTML = guests;
    document.getElementById('turkey-weight').innerHTML = feeds;
};
```

Which is identical to the original handler you wrote, so let's refactor it into:

```
function calculate() {
    var guests = document.getElementById('how-many').value;
    var feeds;

    if (document.getElementById('leftoversyes').checked){
        feeds = guests * 2;
    } else {
        feeds = guests * 1.5;
    }   

    document.getElementById('turkey-number').innerHTML = guests;
    document.getElementById('turkey-weight').innerHTML = feeds;
}

document.getElementById('how-many').onkeyup = calculate;
document.getElementById('leftoversyes').onchange = calculate;
```

Comment: `var feeds = people.value *  (document.getElementById('leftoversyes').checked ? 2 : 1.5);`

Comment: Assuming the OP want's to do that. It's not really clear from the question what they expect.